# jQuery clone() not cloning event bindings, even with on()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a series of custom jQuery events for use in mobile web applications. They work great and have been tested. However, I have run into a small problem which I am having trouble understanding.

I am using `.clone()` on a few elements within the DOM, which contain a button. The button has some of the custom events bound to it (the events are bound using `.on()`), but. Unfortunately, when I use jQuery's `.clone()`, the bindings are not preserved, and I have to add them again.

Has anyone encountered this before, does someone know of a potential work around? I thought that using `.on()` was supposed to preserve the binding for elements that exist now, or in the future?

Comment: "I thought that using .on() was supposed to preserve the binding for elements that exist now, or in the future?" - This has little to do with `.clone`; it's jQuery's event delegation logic and works if you pass an additional selector to `.on`.

Answer (score 235, accepted):

I think you should use this overload of the [.clone()](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) method:

```
$element.clone(true, true);
```

> **clone( [withDataAndEvents] [, deepWithDataAndEvents] )**
>
> **withDataAndEvents**: A Boolean indicating whether event handlers and data should be copied along with the elements. The default value is false.
>
> **deepWithDataAndEvents**: A Boolean indicating whether event handlers and data for all children of the cloned element should be copied. By default its value matches the first argument's value (which defaults to false).

---

Beware that `.on()` does not actually bind the events to the targets but to the element you are delegating to. So if you have:

```
$('#container').on('click', '.button', ...);
```

The events are actually binded to `#container`. When a click on a `.button` element occurs, it bubbles up to the `#container` element The element which triggered the event is evaluated upon the selector parameter of `.on()` and if it matches, the event handler is executed. This is how event delegation works.

If you clone the element #container, you have to deep clone with events and data for the bindings made with `.on()` to be preserved.

This would not be necessary if you were using `.on()` on a parent of `#container`.

Comment: Never knew `.clone()` accepted arguments. FML. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @DidierGhys Thanks, I've been struggling with `.clone()` not cloning the `.data()` (both `data-xxxx="somedata"` and data in the DOM).. This fixes it too!

Comment: Excellent, i had to make a  `click` event to append the new cloned div. `ready` was not working