# How to trigger event on cloned/inserted element in DOM?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am not able to trigger event on element I clone/insert to the DOM.

Check the fiddle [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/27uPH/1/).

HTML:

```
<div class="A">[THIS IS DIV A]</div>
<div class="B">CLICK TO CLONE DIV A</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.A').on("click",null,function() {    
    alert('DIV A CLICK');           
});

$('.B').on("click",null,function() {        
    $('.A').clone().insertAfter('.A');          
});
```

If I click on a cloned `DIV A`, nothing happens.

How can I trigger event on cloned element?

Comment: Possible dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9549643/jquery-clone-not-cloning-event-bindings-even-with-on

Comment: That's officialy a dup. Ill delete it. I flagged it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two solutions I propose.

Firstly, and the better option in this case, would be to add the `true` argument to `clone()`, for example in this case it would be:

```
$('.A').clone(true).insertAfter('.A');
```

As first argument of `clone()` represents:

> "A Boolean indicating whether event handlers and data should be copied
>   along with the elements. The default value is false." - [**jQuery API section for clone()**](http://api.jquery.com/clone/).

This means all bound events will be kept on each cloned element.

[**jsFiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/27uPH/2/)

---

The second option, probably not the way to go for this example, would be to use `on()`'s event delegation feature:

> "Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from
>   descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time." - [**jQuery API section for on()**](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

In this case:

```
$(document).on("click", ".A", function() { ...
```

Now, every new element with the class `.A` will be have this click event attached to it, even cloned elements.

[**jsFiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/RpB99/2/)