# Events on cloned elements?

Tags: jquery

I have this on click:

```
$('.btn-delete').on('click', function(){console.log('delete')});
```

I then clone a div:

```
this.fileTemplate = $('.file:first').remove().clone(true);
```

Later I add the clone back to the page.

'delete' fails to log

The HTML:

```
<li class="file">
   <button class="btn-delete">&times;</button>
</li>
```

Comment: On clone, run a method to rebind/reattach the handler.

Comment: the problem is confusing, you should post more HTML code, what's the relation between your div and the button, ...

Comment: @KingKing I'll post the hTML

Comment: Try to clone first and remove the element afterwards.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery clone() not cloning event bindings, even with on()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9549643/jquery-clone-not-cloning-event-bindings-even-with-on) and many many others

Comment: @Juhana In this case, I think `.clone()` is the wrong thing to use anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're not cloning the button itself, but a parent, you need to do a deep clone:

```
this.fileTemplate = $('.file:first').clone(true,true);
$('.file:first').remove();
```

http://api.jquery.com/clone/#clone-withDataAndEvents-deepWithDataAndEvents

---

However, if you're removing the element anyway, you don't need to clone it at all -- just store the div with all of its events by using `.detach()` instead of `.remove()`:

```
this.fileTemplate = $('.file:first').detach();
```

http://api.jquery.com/detach/

To add copies of that element, deep-clone it after it's detached:

```
clone_copy = this.fileTemplate.clone(true,true);
clone_copy.appendTo('#container');
```

Comment: re: detach - when I wish to add multiple templates back to the page will I need to use clone?

Comment: I think by default the second argument (in `clone()`) is ***the same with*** the first argument, so `clone(true)` is enough.

Comment: @panthro the first should work, that's how you do it, clone the element first and then remove the original element, it's hard to write it in ***one line***, that's your problem. You tried using ***one line*** to solve it, but it's not easy to do that way in this case.