# jQuery functions not working on cloned element

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, clone

I've an element which I clone, there are some simple jQuery events/functions on them like a click action (I've set a log.console in this function) to do some small actions.

When I clone the element, it seems my jquery functions won't work anymore on the cloned element (real element still find).

Is there an reason for the behavior, and how can I solve this?

(update)

My clone, and my remove button. I've added true in the clone function but still nothing is happening.

```
    $('.clone-row').click(function() {

        var row = $(this).prev().prev();
        $(row).clone(true, true).append('<span class="remove">remove</span>').hide().appendTo('.clones').css('opacity', 0).slideDown(350).animate({ opacity: 1 },{ queue: false, duration: 'slow' });

    });
    // clone works fine..

    $('.remove').click(function(){

        console.log('remove');

    });
    // nothing happens
```

Many thanks!

Comment: Use `$element.clone(true, true);` from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9549643/jquery-clone-not-cloning-event-bindings-even-with-on

Answer (score 9):

You need to use the `.clone( [withDataAndEvents ] [, deepWithDataAndEvents ] )`:

```
$.clone( true, true )
```

> A Boolean indicating whether event handlers and data should be copied along with the elements.

By default, this is `false`!

Comment: Thank you for this answer, I've tried to edit the clone with these changes but still nothing happens. I've updated my post with the clone/remove code

Answer (score 0):

change

```
 $(element).click(handler);
```

to

```
 $(element).on("click",handler);
```