# Jquery UI: Draggable drag event not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to fire the "drag" on a draggable() but nothing happens when I drag it?
This my code:

```
  $('.agenda-cloned-object').draggable({
   drag: function( event, ui ) {},
   cursor: "move",
   revert: "invalid",
  });

  $( ".agenda-cloned-object" ).on( "drag", function( event, ui ) { console.log("TEST") } );
```

**Edit:** Appearantly the drag event does not work on a cloned draggable, is there any fix for this?

Comment: can you add relevant code in a snippet?

Comment: have you any error in console ?

Comment: `.on()` binds an event handler. To *fire* the event programatically, use `.trigger()`

Comment: I have no errors and there is no other code next to a droppable.

Comment: Instantiate the draggable after you clone the element.

Comment: Maybe the `draggable` plugin doesn't fire the `drag` event? Also, why not use the `drag` callback?

Comment: Right. Cloned elements don't keep their originals event bindings. Take a look at this answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/9549716/989920)

Answer (score 0):

I can see the event being fired in Chrome v60 on OSX: https://jsfiddle.net/tb061q8o/

The class name "clone" implies your original code was more complicated. I encourage you to try and boil the problem down to a minimum possible reproduce and share it in JsFiddle.

Also, you are declaring the event handler twice. You could just do this:

```
$('.agenda-cloned-object').draggable({
   drag: function( event, ui ) { console.log("TEST") },
   cursor: "move",
   revert: "invalid",
});
```