# The element that I cloned,function doesnt work included in cloned element

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

```
          if(itemCode == currentHotelCode) {
            $('.search-map__item > div').html($(this).clone());
            $('.search-map__item .search-item-slider').slick('reinit');
          }
```

i want to reinit slick slider because position changed but that returns error undefined.

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'reinit' of undefined something like that.

Comment: You may need to clone with dataAndEvents and most likely deep. Read the documentation: https://api.jquery.com/clone/

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9549643/jquery-clone-not-cloning-event-bindings-even-with-on

Comment: well if it is cloned, it is new and never been initiated

Answer (score 1):

Use `append` to add a dom element to another one, html takes actual html string.

```
$('.search-map__item > div').empty().append($(this).clone(true, true));
```

Comment: Try: `$('.search-map__item > div').empty().append($(this).clone(true, true));`

Comment: @AtheistP3ace that makes sense since its trying to reinitialize