# jQuery input validation not working after on newly created input field with jquery append function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i'm using jQuery append function to clone the input fields on front-end, it is working fine but the issue is i have validation on parent element, it is not working on the newly append input fields. This is my jQuery code.

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $("#addChild").click(function() {
    $(".name-field:first").clone().find("input").val("").end()
      .removeAttr("id")
      .appendTo("#additionalselects")
      .append($('<a class="delete" href="#"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>'));
  });
  $("body").on('click', ".delete", function() {
    $(this).closest(".name-field").remove();
  });
});
//Validation
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.name-field').on('input', function() {
    // added for bit of simplicity or you can directly get valuess
    var name = $('input[name="firstname"]').val();
    var date = $('input[name="date"]').val();
    if (name != "" && date != "") {
      // values seems filled remove class  
      $('#stepname').removeClass('disabled');
    } else {
      // user has emptied some input so add class again.
      $('#stepname').addClass('disabled');
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="name-field" class="name-field row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 childname">
    <div class="field text-left">
      <label class="text-left">Name of child</label>
      <input id="firstname" class="firstname" name="firstname" type="text" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 dateofbirth">
    <div class="field text-left">
      <label class="text-left">Date of birth</label>
      <input type="text" class="date" id="thedate" name="date" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<a href="#" id="stepname" class="btn">Next Step</a>
```

Can anyone help me with this, how can achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is the validation code?

Comment: Try .clone(true, true) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9549643/jquery-clone-not-cloning-event-bindings-even-with-on

Comment: share html code also

Comment: @ Rohan i have updated my code.

Comment: I cannot see any element with the id `addChild` in your html code

Comment: You're using event delegation for the `.delete` buttons, why not use it for the `.name-field`s as well?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Answer (score 0):

As you are adding `.name-field` dynamically so event are not binding to the new rows try to change your parent element like,

```
$('#additionalselects').on('input','.name-field input',function(){
//^^^ use other static element or document if not works
    var parent = $(this).closest('.name-field'); // get the parent of focused input
    var name = parent.find('input[name="firstname"]').val();
    var date = parent.find('input[name="date"]').val();
    $('#stepname').toggleClass('disabled',(!name || !date));
});
```

Also you should make the below changes in your HTML,

1. Remove all `id` which are part of cloning
2. Make an array of fields which are to be cloned like `firstname[]`

Comment: I did all the changes, when there is only parent element it is not removing the disabled class.

Comment: I think this code looking only in #additionalselects, ignoring the parent.