# Can't listen to cloned keyup inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery

Sorry if this is basic.

After reading here i changed :

```
 $('input,textarea').keyup(function()
```

to

```
$('input,textarea').on('keyup', function()
```

On my cloned element :

```
   var cln = item.cloneNode(true); //true
```

and i can only listen to `divs` that where in my document on load, not the ones who cloned later.

I have also tried :

```
   var cln = item.cloneNode(true, true);
```

after reading this : [jQuery clone() not cloning event bindings, even with on()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9549643/jquery-clone-not-cloning-event-bindings-even-with-on)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you append the cloned element to the `.container`, Try

```
$('.container').on('keyup', 'input,textarea', function(){...
```

**Demo:**

```js
$('.container').on('keyup', 'input,textarea', function(){
  console.log(this.value);
});

//var cln = item.cloneNode(true); //true
$('input').clone().appendTo('.container');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <input />
  <textarea>Hi</textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks a lot. but how can i clone with events in js ?